# Rails 5.2 credentials.yaml.enc and master.key not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, credentials, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm setting up active storage for a new app, and haven't been able to get the app running on production after setting up my amazon credentials.

1. I've included my s3 bucket credentials in my `credentials.yaml.enc` file
2. I've added my `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` env variable to Heroku.
3. I've set up my s3 bucket in the storage.yml file according to [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#amazon-s3-service).
4. I've added the `config.active_storage.service = :amazon` line to my production.rb.
5. I've added `config.require_master_key = true` to my production.rb

When I try running my app on Heroku, it doesn't load. Doing $ Heroku run rails console gives me the error:

```
"/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sigv4-1.0.2/lib/aws-sigv4/signer.rb:517:in `extract_credentials_provider': Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`: (Aws::Sigv4::Errors::MissingCredentialsError)
missing credentials, provide credentials with one of the following options:
- :access_key_id and :secret_access_key
- :credentials
- :credentials_provider"
```

As far as I can tell I've set up my credentials the way Rails 5.2 intended. I've tried all sorts of asset precompiling stuff to no avail. When I try adding my amazon credentials as env. variables in Heroku, the app runs fine in production. Any idea what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 9):

Could it be that you forgot to add `config.require_master_key = true` to your `production.rb`?

Comment: My issue was that I forgot to set RAILS_MASTER_KEY in production, but this config change still helped me find that issue.

Comment: Nope, I have that.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve had this problem before, seems to be a bug on Heroku.

You should just set up your environment variables through the dashboard on Heroku on the settings tab.

Then you can access that using ENV[‘NAME_OF_YOUR_VARIABLE’]

This fixed my problem.

Also check your Heroku logs very well, by scrolling up to ensure all gems were installed.

Comment: Thanks for answering - unfortunately this is the only option that's worked for me, rendering the rails 5 credentials encryption system pretty useless.

Comment: @spitz Glad, it helped. This is probably a bug and will definitely be fixed in future versions of rails.

Answer (score 3):

Double check that you have the correct key in your `config/credentials.yml.enc` file. I had one key inverted- `secret_key_access` instead of `secret_access_key`, and was getting the same error. Fixing the key name in `config/credentials.yml.enc` fixed it for me.

In your rails console (locally), run:

`Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id)`

and

`Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key)`

to make sure they have values.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, this was dumb. Mystery solved. My credentials were commented out in the `credentials.yaml.enc` file - I was adding them to the top of the file with the default aws example, which is commented out.

Comment: You accepted your own answer, when [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50877073/7311767) looks to be pretty much the same?

Comment: @StephenRauch that answer's a little different; my credentials were correct, it's just that they were commented out.

Comment: Fair enough...  But I would just say that someone took the time to answer your question, with what looked to me (I don't know the topic) to be a pretty close answer.  Yet you didn't upvote it.  The answer said to be sure you had the correct key.  Well, you did not have the correct key since you commented it out?  So, to me that answer was quite close.  You are entitled to accept any answer you want, and vote any way you want.  But, I would suggest it is good karma to up vote the answers on your questions which provided useful information, even if they were not exactly right.  Cheers.

Comment: I see your point, and just upvoted it. I appreciate you being a steward of the community - I'm newish here and am still learning the rules of conduct. I wanted to include my own answer to be as specific about the solution as possible for other folks.